# Java Date conversion

Tags: java, date, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Hi, how would I convert a string, for example "5/22/2011" into Sunday, May 22?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ben, don't rant, just ask to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("5/22/2011");
String s = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd").format(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the class [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
The javadoc give a good description of the parameters

You can use one format to convert into a java Date object and then another to convert back into the second string